# ffmpeg - error processing files generated by premier pro 2022

Tags: ffmpeg

Please help with the error, trying to re-encode the source file produced with prores 4444+alpha. Alpha channel is required in my case.

I've tried two separate options, both are erroring out:

```
$ ffmpeg -i Input.mxf -vcodec prores_ks -profile:v 4 -y Output.mxf
```

I'm getting this output

```
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Input #0, mxf, from 'Input.mxf':
  Metadata:
    operational_pattern_ul: 060e2b34.04010101.0d010201.01010100
    uid             : b52947e8-d982-11ec-9a2d-b42e99ab5f4d
    generation_uid  : b52947e9-d982-11ec-a612-b42e99ab5f4d
    company_name    : Adobe Inc.
    product_name    : Premiere Pro
    product_version_num: 2.0.0.0.1
    product_version : 22.4.0
    application_platform: Mac OS X
    product_uid     : 0c3919fe-46e8-11e5-a151-feff819cdc9f
    toolkit_version_num: 5.3.6.0.1
    modification_date: 2022-05-22T03:53:15.000000Z
    material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D1113000000F88BD5002197058861C9B42E99AB5F4D
    timecode        : 00:00:00;00
  Duration: 00:00:59.66, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32803 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: prores (4444) (ap4h / 0x68347061), yuva444p12le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B34010101050101051213D028BEF88BD500219705880089B42E99AB5F4D
      file_package_name: Source Package
      track_name      : Track 1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (prores (native) -> prores (prores_ks))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mxf, to 'Output.mxf':
  Metadata:
    operational_pattern_ul: 060e2b34.04010101.0d010201.01010100
    uid             : b52947e8-d982-11ec-9a2d-b42e99ab5f4d
    generation_uid  : b52947e9-d982-11ec-a612-b42e99ab5f4d
    timecode        : 00:00:00;00
    material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D1113000000F88BD5002197058861C9B42E99AB5F4D
    product_version_num: 2.0.0.0.1
    modification_date: 2022-05-22T03:53:15.000000Z
    application_platform: Mac OS X
    product_uid     : 0c3919fe-46e8-11e5-a151-feff819cdc9f
    toolkit_version_num: 5.3.6.0.1
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: prores (ap4h / 0x68347061), yuva444p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbn
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B34010101050101051213D028BEF88BD500219705880089B42E99AB5F4D
      file_package_name: Source Package
      track_name      : Track 1
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 prores_ks
[mxf @ 0x7fbbbc008200] could not get prores profile0:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Operation not permitted
Error writing trailer of Output.mxf: Unknown error occurred
frame=   33 fps= 27 q=-0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.027x    
video:67kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

Above I can't even fully see the error since the red text over black background covers the screen:
[image]

I have also tried the following encoding options:

```
 -c:v qtrle -pix_fmt argb
```

to which, I'm getting the following error:

```
track 0: could not find essence container ul, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
Conversion failed!
```

In case this is helpful, I'm displaying MediaInfo for the source file:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use mxf wrapper, I've had this issue before, what helped is to process the output as MOV. This solved my issue and this is how I request agency to send me their output, if alpha is needed:
Preset: custom
Format: QuickTime
Video Codec: Animation

then, under **basic video settings**:

expend **more**

- Depth, and choose **8-bpc+alpha**

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this option later tonight and will post the update here.

Comment: This worked great, thank you Brazil, really appreciate your input. The great thing is that, as far as I know, the Animation codec is lossless, mostly. For my purposes, this works great.